# Legal test (on pre-producten Stage) slows down deliveries. How can I structure or accelerate this process?

Tags: test-management, qa-developer, continuous-integration, team-management, development-process

In the course of, among other things, legal test procedures in the staging area, we have integrated a further step, namely pre-production, in which our lawyers check the texts of the pages to be published for corresponding content. Imprint obligation, data security and much other. Until then, the normal process of unit testing, integration, acceptance, etc. is complete.

Up to this process everything runs automatically, the legal test on the Pre-Production however is offside of any planning.

Reason: Lawyers need time and that's exactly why you couldn't plan this process, not even via a timebox.

But the deliveries are delayed more and more. Do you have any idea how to speed up such legal tests ?

Without the approval by the lawyers no new page goes online.

Answer (score 2):

Who writes the text for the application when creating tasks - lawyers or someone else?

My suggestion:

1. Get specifications for texts directly from lawyers
2. Implement automated front end testing (maybe some sort of visual testing tool)
3. Send the results of the tests to lawyer team
4. Lawyer team approves / rejects the results of front end testing

This way they are incorporated into the process from the start (empowers them) and they do not have to check the whole application - just the test result reports (less grunt work for them).

Comment: Interesting approach, I need to think about it.

Comment: Do a minimal experiment with 1 piece of text and one test.  See how it goes.  Repeat with any lessons learned from the previous experiment.  Keep repeating. Welcome to Agile.